# Delete relations efficiency in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I've got a collection of duplicate relations of relations that I need to tidy up.

The table might be described like this

```
posts
id: 1

impressions
id: 1, post_id: 1, created_at: 2020-01-02
id: 2, post_id: 1, created_at: 2020-01-02
id: 3, post_id: 1, created_at: 2020-01-03

demographic_distribution
id: 1, impression_id: 1
id: 2, impression_id: 1
id: 3, impression_id: 2
id: 4, impression_id: 2
id: 5, impression_id: 3
```

I intend to remove the impression with id 1, but due to foreign key constraints, I would need to remove the related demographic_distributions first.

From demographic_distributions I would want to remove ids 1 & 2.

The following query works, but it's not very efficient. I have around 78 millions rows in the demographic_distribution table, and I have other similar sized related tables.

```sql
DELETE FROM demographic_distribution
WHERE impression_id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM impressions AS i1
  WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM impressions AS i2
    WHERE i2.post_id = i1.post_id
      AND i2.created_at::date = i1.created_at::date
    GROUP BY i2.post_id    
  )
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not very efficient"? How are you determining this? How many rows are you trying to delete? Out of how many?

Comment: And why the double nesting? This seems equivalent: `DELETE FROM demographic_distribution
WHERE impression_id NOT IN (     SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM impressions GROUP BY post_id,  created_at::date) ;`

Comment: There are duplicates in the impression table too. I'll be removing those in a separate query. The demographic_distribution table has about 78million rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can do all in a single [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

```
with deleted_impressions as (
  delete from impressions i1
  where exists (select * 
                from impressions i2
                where i2.id > i1.id
                  and i2.created_at = i1.created_at)
  returning id
), delete_reg_impressions as (
  delete from regional_impressions
  where impression_id in (select id 
                        from deleted_impressions)
) 
delete from demographic_distribution
where impression_id in (select id 
                        from deleted_impressions);
```

First the duplicates from `impressions` are removed and all IDs that are returned from that query are then used to delete the corresponding rows in `demographic_distribution` as this is done in a single (atomic) statement the foreign keys are still valid.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards CTE, that looks really useful. Unfortunately in my case, I have a second, regional_distribution table of similar size that would also need those impression ids.

Comment: @KevinCarmody: you can add another delete to the statement without problems

Comment: appreciate the update. your edit introduced a syntax error